# Cut off text in a div if it exceeds set width?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, text, html

On a website I am working on users can add a heading to a section of a page.A simple example:

```
M11-001 - loss of container and goods from Manchester
```

With some headings the content can be quite in-depth. In reality, for the heading at least, this content isn't always needed. The first few words would suffice to differentiate between records.

I could just set overflow:hidden to the div and ruthlessly cut of anything outside of the set width.

I would prefer to add ... To the end. Like so:

```
M11-001 - loss of container...
```

So three full-stops would be added after either X width or X characters.

Is this possible with CSS, or maybe JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean after X characters or X words? You could use `substring` and concatenate it with `'...'`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Something like this? http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

**Text-Overflow**

> The text-overflow declaration allows
>   you to deal with clipped text: that
>   is, text that does not fit into its
>   box. The ellipsis value causes three
>   periods to be appended to the text.

Comment: An advantage is that copied text does not include the `...` but rather the complete text.

Comment: Great.  Is there anything else you need to mark this question as "answered"?

Comment: Amazing! Had 5+ lines to handle this with substring and concatenations. Very smooth

Comment: Work perfectly, `white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis; `.

Comment: For multi-line text, sometimes you may need to cut off only last line exceeding text. I found a solution here for that particular case. https://medium.com/@elad/trimming-multi-lines-in-css-5ae59d5e6d84