# How can I determine how much of a string will fit in a certain width?

Tags: c#, winforms, string

Hi
I have a problem with adjusting length of text so that it fits to form's length.
In my form I placed a label which is responsible for displaying some long text. However the text might be so long that it won't fit to form. That is why I want to shorten this text and add ... to the end.

The problem is that I don't know how to efficiently calculate the substring of maximal lenght which would fit in form. So far I only managed to check if given text is too long (I use the method `MeasureString` from `Graphics` class).
What would be the best way to calculate max substring which would fit in form (substring which `width < form.Width` )?

Comment: For a moment I thought this was a joke post asking how long a piece of string is...

Comment: Maybe you just need to set the [`Label.AutoEllipsis`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis.aspx) property.

Comment: Well you have to consider that letters do not have the same size(in many fonts, except monospace): e.g. 'W' is not as small as 'i', so you can generaly not assume that a word with the same number of letters have the same size.

Comment: @Rob - oooh, shiny! I learned something today :)

Comment: @Rob: thanks, had missed that one.

Comment: This is a repeat of a question I just saw, the answer was text-overflow

Comment: Hmm, Actually I just found it, its slightly different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707420/cut-off-text-in-a-div-if-it-exceeds-set-width

Answer (score 1):

Only reliable way I know of is shorten your string until it fits which you can check by using `MeasureString()`, there is no reverse method unfortunately (given a width, how much of this string would fit), so you are going to have to build that yourself.

Comment: If you do a binary search on the string, it shouldn't be that hard to figure out what length of it will fit on the form.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to this problem since I ran into it myself today. My ToolStripStatusLabel is set to auto-size, but it was exceeding the width of the parent control and thus hiding itself. My solution is specifically for use with the [ToolStripStatusLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.aspx) control. Since that is the case this control does not provide a MaxWidth property or the AutoEllipsis property. It also will not generate a Graphics object for me since it is not part of the control family. This method can be altered to work with two Control objects, not much changes except for the parameter. My options were quite limited so I fabricated this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// If a child ToolStripStatusLabel is wider than it's parent then this method will attempt to
/// make the child's text fit inside of the parent's boundaries. An ellipsis can be appended
/// at the end of the text to indicate that it has been truncated to fit.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="child">Child ToolStripStatusLabel</param>
/// <param name="parent">Parent control where the ToolStripStatusLabel resides</param>
/// <param name="appendEllipsis">Append an "..." to the end of the truncated text</param>
public static void TruncateChildTextAccordingToControlWidth(ToolStripStatusLabel child, Control parent, bool appendEllipsis)
{
    //If the child's width is greater than that of the parent's
    if(child.Size.Width > parent.Size.Width)
    {
        //Get the number of times that the child is oversized [child/parent]
        decimal decOverSized = (decimal)(child.Size.Width) / (decimal)(parent.Size.Width);

        //Get the new Text length based on the number of times that the child's width is oversized.
        int intNewLength = (int)(child.Text.Length / (2M * decOverSized)); //Doubling as a buffer (Magic Number).

        //If the ellipsis is to be appended
        if(appendEllipsis) //then 3 more characters need to be removed to make room for it.
            intNewLength = intNewLength - 3;

        //If the new length is negative for whatever reason
        if(intNewLength < 0) 
            intNewLength = 0; //Then default it to zero

        //Truncate the child's Text accordingly
        child.Text = child.Text.Substring(0, intNewLength);

        //If the ellipsis is to be appended
        if(appendEllipsis) //Then do this last
            child.Text += "...";
    }
}
```

I will be the first to point out that I did a dreadful thing and included a magic number! I apologize, but the 2M is a buffer. I couldn't find a better way to do that yet, when/if I find a way I will be sure to come back and update it here. I needed the magic number because the percentage I calculated is accurate, but in order to fit the child control inside of the parent well enough I needed about twice what was being returned.

I'm sure this will not be entirely accurate depending on the label font size and other factors, but hey its a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to make my statusbar text fit by stripping characters from the beginning of the string.  Maybe you can modify it to your needs

```
        status.Text = status.Text + " | " + newText;
        while (TextRenderer.MeasureText(status.Text, status.Font).Width > status.Width)
            status.Text = status.Text.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the text word by word and meanwhile move the cursor point ahead until it reaches the end of line (width of the form). I had a similar problem but I was drawing the text on the form, I changed my code to fit your need.

```
private bool WriteWord(string word)
{
    Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(word + "  ", Font);
    if (cursor.X + size.Width > Width)
    {
        // you reached the end of the line
        return false;
    }
    label1.Text += word + "  "; // add the word to label.
    cursor.X += size.Width;
    return true;
}
Point Cursor;
private string FindMaxSubstring(string text)
{
    string[] tokens = text.Split(new string[] { " "}); 
    string substring ="";
    Cursor.X = 0;
    foreach (var t in tokens)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Trim()))
        {
            if (!WriteWord(t))
                return substring;
            substring += t;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoSize` property of the label to true, then split your text to tokens and add them token by token to the `label.Text` until `label.Width > Width.`